# How to use Jenkins github user credentials to access github api in my script?

Tags: jenkins, git, jenkins-plugins, github, authentication

I have a Jenkins job `foo` that works perfectly well. It is authenticated with `jenkins_foo_user`. It is able to clone the repo and checkout the right branch.

In my codebase, I have another script - `query_github.py` a script used to query Github API to get information such as commits and pull request. To be able to use this API I need an access token.

I want to be able to use the jenkins user access token to authenticate and access the github credentials.

How do I do this?

Note: Using the Github Enterprise version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want the [Credentials Plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/credentials).

The administrator of the Jenkins instance can add the plugin, then add the credential (access token) that the job needs. Then, in the job, [use the credential](https://github.com/jenkinsci/credentials-plugin/blob/master/docs/user.adoc#using-credentials) as a variable.

See the [documentation](https://github.com/jenkinsci/credentials-plugin/blob/master/docs/user.adoc) for more details.